# Update XML with an SQL query

Tags: python, sql, xml

Let's say we have the following XML file:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring("""
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>Hello</c>
            <d>1234</d>
        </b>
        <b>
            <c>Bonjour</c>
            <d>5678</d>
        </b>        
    </a>
    """)
```

**How could it be possible to update the XML with a SQL-like query language?**

Example (pseudo-code):

```
etree.query("""UPDATE a.b SET c.text = 'foo' WHERE d.text = '5678'""")
```

or even more complex chained-queries, such as:

```
UPDATE a.b SET c.text = (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...) WHERE d.text = '5678'
```

The goal is to be able to modify complex XML documents with just one or two lines of code, with a SQL-like syntax. Sidenote: As a comparison, doing this manually with `lxml`, `find`, etc. works, but is much longer.

Comment: XML documents are fundamentally different data structures than relational tables. Hence, you will be hard pressed to find a tidy, compact one-to-one translation of SQL (a set-based language) to traverse nested nodes.

Comment: @Parfait your answer was really useful, it would be great if you can vote to undelete it: it will be useful for future references, and to compare available solutions to modify XML documents :)

Comment: I do not know in other database systems, but Oracle and Oracle XML DB provides a functionality similar to the one you described, based on custom constructs an the use of XQuery. Please, see the relevant [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB4267).

Answer (score 7):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML documents, which shares a few attributes of SQL:

- Special purpose language that can be called by general purpose application layer.
- Industry language not restricted to any language like Python and can be run by [standalone processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) like Saxon and Xalan.
- Declarative style and semantics and can receive parameters from application layer.

Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts which are simply special XML files. To answer your first query, use the conditional XSLT counterpart of `<xsl:choose>`.

**Load Documents**

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("""\
    <a>
        <b>
            <c>Hello</c>
            <d>1234</d>
        </b>
        <b>
            <c>Bonjour</c>
            <d>5678</d>
        </b>        
    </a>""")

xsl = etree.fromstring("""\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- INITIALIZE PARAMETERS -->
    <xsl:param name="c_val"/>
    <xsl:param name="d_val"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- CONDITIONALLY UPDATE <c> -->
    <xsl:template match="c">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="following-sibling::d = $d_val">
                   <xsl:value-of select="$c_val"/>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
                   <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
             </xsl:otherwise>  
         </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>""")
```

**Run Transformation**

```py
# INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
transformer = etree.XSLT(xsl)

# TRANSFORM WITH PARAMETERS
result = transformer(
            root, 
            c_val=etree.XSLT.strparam("foo"),
            d_val=etree.XSLT.strparam("5678")
         )

# OUTPUT RESULT TO CONSOLE
print(result)
# <a>
#   <b>
#     <c>Hello</c>
#     <d>1234</d>
#   </b>
#   <b>
#     <c>foo</c>
#     <d>5678</d>
#   </b>
#</a>
```

Not quite clear about your second query. But if needing to query from a different XML document (counterpart to different SQL table), XSLT maintains the `document()` function and can be called in most places including parameter. Adjust XPath below.

```xml
<xsl:param name="c_val">
   <xsl:value-of select="document('other.xml')/a/b/c[1]">
</xsl:param>
```

If not passing `c_val` from app layer, be sure to remove that parameter in Python, otherwise you will overwrite above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sidenote: I'm still in search of a "close to SQL" solution, because the main interest is that ... you can usually do a lot of work with just *one line* of SQL. Here with XSLT it seems rather complex, needing 20+ lines of templates, with complex-looking syntax, like `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>`. XML + SQL querying would be ... amazing in comparison :)

Comment: Simply that is XSLT with its recursive paradigm. Also, the Identity Transform simply copies XML as is. So just adjust the params and last template to rewrite the specific elements. I edit to directly redesign `c` element. Depending on actual needs, you can work from a *single* template. Yes, it's not a one-liner but with XSLT you avoid looping through nodes on Python side.

Answer (score 1):

At the first look, it seems this is an easy job to do but, in fact, isn't.

The hardest work will be "how to parse the XML **[recursively](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)**", to identify each (node -> sub-node -> sub-sub-node ... ), after that, the building of the query will be a little easier.

I believe that **lxml** library will give you the nodes as **iterable objects**, so they all contain ****iter**()** method which can be executed by **next**, so I believe that standard **python** with **lxml** library is sufficient for the recursive work.

but,
thinking again about the idea (from **XML** to **SQL** query), here the **SQL query** has its own properties, and managing them is a need :

- Database.
- Table.
- Column.
- Statements.

To manage this! **You end up building a medium-size library (and maybe an ORM)** to convert each node to it's correct **SQL** statement.

let consider this :

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>Hello</c>
      <d>1234</d>
   </b>
</a>
```

Nodes must be identified as:

- **a** node is a database.
- **b** node is a table.
- **c** and d are columns.

And that what makes the idea unique and must be self-programmed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if the xml document is presentable as a table.

xml to `dict` with [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)
`dict` to `sqlite` table probably via an ORM or `csv`

Modify table with sql.

`sqlite` to `dict` probably via `csv`
`dict` to xml with [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

Wrap everything in a `class`.

Comment: I have already used xml2dict and similar tools in the past, but here it is not as simple as it seems ;) Please post sample code demonstrating your technique. Thanks!